# Spring-Hibernate started on remote tomcat server is not creating tables. Drop and create works, alo data.sql is picked up correctly on localhost

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, tomcat9

Can not find the crucial reason why tables are not getting created under seamingly same conditions.

Spring tool suite 4.x is used for building the project/netbeans does the same.... ; the project is a maven built collection of code; both localhost and remote servers are using same mysql. the server is an Apache Tomcat 9 on Debian ...

Application.properties that works just fine on localhost:

```
spring.datasource.name=JAVAMAN2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JAVAMAN2?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
#spring.datasource.password=

spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

This here makes no difference

```
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<!-- BASIC  -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING MAIL  -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- THYMELEAF  -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL Connector-J -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JODA TIME  -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- DEVTOOLS  -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CONFIG PROCESOR  -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google GSON  -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING SECURITY  -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TOMCAT  -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

There are no errors shown/logged in console. The application just runs, but wont create tables.

A few example entities
User

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "ENABLED", nullable = false)
    private Integer enabled;

    @Column(name = "CLIENT_DB", nullable = false)
    private String client_db;

    @Column(name = "KOM_SIF", nullable = false)
    private String komSif;

    @Column(name = "ITC_KOM_SIF", nullable = false)
    private String itcKomSif;

    @Column(name = "UNIKEY", nullable = true)
    private String unikey;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Authorities> authorities = new HashSet<>();
```

Authority

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
//import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
//import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
//import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "authorities")
public class Authorities {
  @Id
  //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "AUTHORITY")
  private String authority;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private User user;
```

getters and setters intensionally omitted from this post ...

Comment: You say just runs. Are there no exceptions when you access the app?

Comment: Provide any one entity class also

Comment: Thank you for the response. Did not add any code on the start since it builds and can be started (=runs) on local server and can be deployed on remote server without any errors/exceptions as well - edit: added USer and Authorities entities now. The point is : it should open all the tables on the remote server too, the same way it does on my localhost , but it just starts (=runs) and just wont open any tables. On localhost, it opens like 12 tables, 3 of them geting filled from data.sql too.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it is a `MariaDB` on the remote server, not a `MySQL` one.

I had to replace in the `pom.xml`the mysql connector dependency with:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Also changed 3 lines to the `application.properties`, driver class name, url and db dialect props have been altered

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3308/JAVAMAN2?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect
```

Now it creates the requiered tables the same way as it does with MySQL